# How can I ensure that a user account on my local dev server has the same uid as an account on my production server?

Tags: 7, rules, features

I have a local dev server that I use for testing and a production server.  I have written several rules (with the rules module) that send private messages (using the private message module) to users.

I want these messages to be sent from a special administrative support user; the problem is that this user has a uid of 7 on my local site and 9 on the production site.

Since I am still early in the development process, it is simple enough for me to reset the databases and start over so that the uids are in sync.  However, since this may come up again at a point where it is not convenient to reset, is there a good way to ensure that accounts on different servers have the same UID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not currently possible to export Users into a Feature.**

There's [an open issue](http://drupal.org/node/993076) for adding support to [uuid_features.module](http://drupal.org/project/uuid_features).

Answer (score 0):

If I were you and I had a database access I would export the users table from production to my dev site, after taking a backup from my dev users table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but exporting the users table would be difficult because the relevant user also has authored a large amount of content which would have to be moved as well.  I'm specifically interested in making the UIDs the same.